# Where can I get Apple logo with free license

Tags: apple, icon

I am working on a site that provide free tools, some of the tools are multi-platform and therefore I want to put the Icon of each OS, I already got linux icon and windows icon with free license but I couldnt find the apple one.

does anyone know where can I get it from?

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

See [Apple's software licensing documentation](http://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/) for information regarding the use of Apple's logo with your software.

Apple's logo licenses are *typically* free and require little more than **faxing or posting a signed legal document**.

Additionally, Apple has guidelines regarding where and how each logo or image can be used; be aware of these guidelines.

For software that can run on a Mac, you will want to license the Mac logo.

Comment: Nice page, will go there for the *Firewire* and *Mac OS Universal* logos, but I see **no** guideline disciplining the *White Apple Logo*, there.

Comment: If you can not find the logo on the linked page, you can not use the logo. Apple does not license all its logos.

Answer (score 3):

Logos are covered under trademark rather than copyright, and trademark works a little differently (at least in the US) — as long as you use the mark in a way that has no chance to confuse the consumer to believe that your good or service is really produced by or directly associated with the owner of the mark, you can just use the mark without a license.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that using icons to show OS compatibility would fall under fair use. Just use this logo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apple-logo.png

Comment: "Fair use" is a concept of USA copyright law. Other countries might have something similar, or they might not.

Comment: Good comment by Daniel - its in USA and few other countries. I like limitedimage's suggestion - its very wise to go with what is on Wikipedia. And in this case, I think theoretically, Apple would *like* you to use the image so its definitely fair.

Comment: [File:Apple-logo.png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apple-logo.png) - "This page has been deleted" mh...